# Unable to return session value in views Field

Tags: 7, views, rules, sessions

I am storing a session value via Rules when the user is logged in

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['userkey'] = "12345";
```

Also testing it below there

```
echo $_SESSION['userkey'];
```

Although when I am trying to retrieve this value in my view in a field as Global: PHP

with Value Code:

```
return $_SESSION['userkey'];
```

Output code:

```
<?php
echo $value;
?>
```

It does not return anything. Unsure whether the session is not being set properly or I am retrieving the value incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: Check Drupal logs or Apache/PHP logs and see if you have an error of level `E_NOTICE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `session_start()` from Rules. Drupal calls `session_start()` when firing [`drupal_session_start()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_start/7).

Check out [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) manual on [php.net](http://php.net/)

> As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was
>   previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also,
>   the second session start will simply be ignored.

Screenshot for PHP field settings in Views:

[image]

Comment: I feel its an issue somewhere on the views side, with or without session_start, I am unable to retrieve the value in the view fields

Comment: @pal4life I was able to get session value the way you describe it without session_start just fine. Try to update views_php module and see if it solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, What code did you add in the value code and output code field in your views to get the value?

Comment: @pal4life I added a screenshot in my answer for PHP field settings, check it out and I hope it will for you as well. Make sure to logout and login to see the value on your views.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the screenshot. This made things very clear. Certainly a picture is worth a thousand words. Thanks.

Comment: @pal4life you are welcome :D